# mkChar does not escape percent sign

Tags: c++, r

I have the following code :

```
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <cmath>

extern "C" {
SEXP myChar(int x) {
  /*PrintValue(nam);*/
  SEXP colnames, result;
  PROTECT(colnames = Rf_allocVector(STRSXP,2));
  char buffer[20];
  int n = sprintf(buffer,"%4.2f%%",2.5);
  SET_STRING_ELT(colnames,0,mkChar(buffer));
  n = sprintf(buffer,"%4.2f%c",5.0,0x25);
  SET_STRING_ELT(colnames,1,mkChar(buffer));

  PROTECT(result = Rf_allocVector(VECSXP, 2));
  SEXP scol1 = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP,10));
  SEXP scol2 = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP,10));

  for (size_t k=0;k<10;++k){
      REAL(scol1)[k] = std::pow(k,0.5);
      REAL(scol2)[k] = std::pow(k,0.7);
  }
  SET_VECTOR_ELT(result,0,scol1);
  SET_VECTOR_ELT(result,1,scol2);

  setAttrib(result, R_NamesSymbol, colnames);
  UNPROTECT(4);
  return(result);
}
}
```

I compile like this :

```
R CMD SHLIB myChar.cpp
```

And run the following in my R session :

```
> dyn.load("myChar.so")
> out<-as.data.frame(.Call("myChar"))
> out
       X2.50.     X5.00.
1    0.000000   0.000000
2    1.000000   1.000000
3    1.414214   1.624505
4    1.732051   2.157669
5    2.000000   2.639016
6    2.236068   3.085169
7    2.449490   3.505144
8    2.645751   3.904529
9    2.828427   4.287094
10   3.000000   4.655537
```

My question is why the column names doesn't show the percent sign? I use '%%' to escape the percent sign but in the column names it is converted to a period, i.e. instead of "X2.50%" I get "X2.50.". Is that a feature of mkChar? Is there any other way to convert char array to SEXP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `C/C++` code. The problem arises when you coerce to `data.frame`. Try this:

```
out<-.Call("myChar")
#names are correct
names(out)
#[1] "2.50%" "5.00%"
#now correctly to data.frame, see ?data.frame
out<-data.frame(out,check.names=FALSE)
#      2.50%    5.00%
#1  0.000000 0.000000
#2  1.000000 1.000000
#3  1.414214 1.624505
#4  1.732051 2.157669
#5  2.000000 2.639016
#6  2.236068 3.085169
#7  2.449490 3.505144
#8  2.645751 3.904529
#9  2.828427 4.287094
#10 3.000000 4.655537
```

See the `check.names` argument of `data.frame` to get a grasp of what is going on.

Comment: Yep---data.frame column names are frequently used in subsequent expressions (as eg the formula notation) so `make.names()` is by default called which will suppress the `%`, escape leading digits and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `\045` to represent the percentage symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck

Comment: Try escaping through `\%`, although I think you would've already tried that. Other than this I'm sorry, I'm too out of options.